# Parsing Nested JSON give Unhandled Exception

Tags: android, json, flutter, dart, nested

I am trying to parse complex Nested JSON, I have multiple classes to get down the JSON nests. I am looking for the numbers from this JSON

```
{
  "data": {
    "attributes": {
      "last_analysis_stats": {
        "harmless": 81,
        "malicious": 2,
        "suspicious": 0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but whenever I parse it, I get the error "Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Data'"

the code that I am using is below

```
_GoneSmishinState goneSmishinStateFromJson(String str) => _GoneSmishinState.fromJson(json.decode(str));
String goneSmishinStateToJson(_GoneSmishinState data) => json.encode(data.toJson());


String url = "https://urlhaus-api.abuse.ch/v1/urls/recent/"; //address for URL file

int harmless = 0;

Future<void> main() async {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key:key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: "Gone Smishin'",
      home:  GoneSmishin(),
    );
  }
}


class Data {
  late Attributes attributes;

  Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : attributes = Attributes.fromJson(json["attributes"]);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "attributes": attributes.toJson(),
  };
}

class Attributes {
  late LastAnalysisStats lastAnalysisStats;

  Attributes.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : lastAnalysisStats= LastAnalysisStats.fromJson(json["last_analysis_stats"]);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "last_analysis_stats": lastAnalysisStats.toJson(),
  };
}

class LastAnalysisStats {
  late int harmless;
  late int malicious;
  late int suspicious;

  LastAnalysisStats.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : harmless= json["harmless"],
        malicious= json["malicious"],
        suspicious= json["suspicious"];

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "harmless": harmless,
    "malicious": malicious,
    "suspicious": suspicious,
  };
}



String message = "";
String word = "";
bool isOn = false;

@override
void dispose() {
  myController.dispose();
  //super.dispose();
}
var data = '';

var attributes = '';


String virusTotal = "VirusTotal";
String list = "Whitelist";



final myController = TextEditingController();


class GoneSmishin extends StatefulWidget {
  const GoneSmishin({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _GoneSmishinState createState() => _GoneSmishinState();
}


class _GoneSmishinState extends State<GoneSmishin> {
  _GoneSmishinState({Key? key}) : super();
  late Data data;
  _GoneSmishinState.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : data= Data.fromJson(json["data"]);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "data": data.toJson(),
  };
  urlHausParseBox() async {
    String url = myController.text;
    var urlEncoded = base64.encode(utf8.encode(myController.text));
    var urlNoPadding = urlEncoded.replaceAll(new RegExp(r'='), '');

    final response2 = await http.get(
      Uri.parse("https://www.virustotal.com/api/v3/urls/$urlNoPadding"),
      headers: <String, String>{
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'x-apikey': '11111111111111111111111111111111'
      },
    );

    print(urlEncoded);
    print(response2.body);

    if (response2.statusCode == 200) {
      setState(() {
        final decoded = json.decode(response2.body);
        data = decoded['data'];
});

    if ((data.attributes.lastAnalysisStats.malicious + data.attributes.lastAnalysisStats.suspicious)>= 2) {
      setState(() {
        virusTotal = 'Found in VirusTotal - Possibly Malicious';
      });
    } else
    if ((data.attributes.lastAnalysisStats.suspicious + data.attributes.lastAnalysisStats.suspicious) <= 1) {
      setState(() {
        virusTotal = 'Found in VirusTotal - Probably not Malicious';
        print((data.attributes.lastAnalysisStats.suspicious + data.attributes.lastAnalysisStats.suspicious));
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        virusTotal = 'Not found in VirusTotal';
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to chage this code

```
   setState(() {
        final decoded = json.decode(response2.body);
        data = decoded['data'];
      });
```

to

```
 setState(() {
      final decoded = json.decode(response2.body);
          data = Data.fromJson(decoded['data']);
      });
```

Comment: you are now my favourite person on earth xxxxxxxx

Comment: @TaylorSparks haha, thx. Btw, you can upvote if you found helpful :)